# Sitecore Virtual User is lost on new page request

Tags: user-profile, membership-provider

We have created a Virtual User in Sitecore (to reside in Sitecore memory) - we are able to see the virtual user with all the profile data we save but on a redirect to a new page, the Virtual user and its data is lost. We are just seeing a normal anonymous user which is not a virtual user.

The virtual user is created using the below code syntax -

```
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(@"domain\user", true);
if (user != null)
{
   string domainRole = @"domain\role";
   if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.Exists(domainRole))
   {
     user.Roles.Add(Role.FromName(domainRole));
   }

   user.Profile.Email = "user@domain.com";
   user.Profile["Custom Property"] = "Custom Value";
   user.Profile.Save();
   Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(user);
}
```

Are we missing something to make the virtual user available on all pages of our application.

Comment: virtual user exists in a single session. are you sure that none of your code is clearing it?

Comment: No Andrey, we are not clearing any session values. Also, currently we are doing this on a single server instance.

Comment: Do you see something related to this in the log files? Do you see the session cookie? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBafP.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBafP.jpg)

Comment: No Dennis - nothing specific to sessions in log. Moreover i have found a weird think happening - the Virtual User is persisting for a Anonymous user but for a Logged-in user its not persisting.

Comment: Are you trying this master databse or web db? I faced this issue on the master db (during dev phase) but not on the web db.

Comment: @sc.kp - currently doing in dev phase.To add here - the virtual user is created but the moment we navigate the user from the login page to any internal page the user data is lost.

Comment: yup i had the same issue, check your database.. your Context.site.database should be pointing to web. Virtual users work well with web db.

Comment: Since I can't comment, was there ever any resolution to this issue? We are experiencing the exact same thing. Switching to web db does not help.

Comment: We're also seeing something similar using Sitecore  8.2 (161221).  For us the virtual user with extended (custom) properties works fine for the most part, but occasionally users report an issue which to me looks like the extended properties have been dropped.

Comment: Is there any solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: For those experiencing problems, are you running on a multi-server setup, e.g. more than 1 CD server? How are they load-balanced, are you using sticky sessions?

Comment: I've had a almost similar issue and got a hotfix from siteore.

Comment: @Thomas - can you share some details around what was done by Sitecore as part of the Hotfix update. This can help us understand more on the issue.

Comment: The issue is only if you use MVC, the user is logout and isn't correctly logged in again. It could be related but not sure, the sitecore Ticket number is 495161

Answer (score 5):

I recently came across with the same situation where we have created Virtual user and also created some custom property. At the early stage it was working properly as Sitecore user works but one day suddenly it stopped working.

In my solution still Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated this was always true but all the profile properties was empty at this time. Then I started digging into our latest change we made for project and found we just added a view rendering on LogIn page (Login Item). And that rendering was having

```
var customPropValue = Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.GetCustomProperty("customProp");
```

code and some other code too.

To just test I removed the rendering from the login item and it seems functionality again started working because after login it was either redirecting me to home page or RedirectURL page.

Then it was proved that Virtual user was not working because of the new rendering which contains code to get custom property of user. I again applied that rendering to item and this time I removed all other code from the rendering and still keep

```
var customPropValue = Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.GetCustomProperty("customProp");
```

code into it and this time again issue was same I lost all the profile properties of virtual user.

At last I removed the

```
  var customPropValue = Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.GetCustomProperty("customProp");
```

code from the rendering and it started working for me.

I want that code on other pages but not on login page so I added a condition on top if page is login page then don't execute this code and execute for all other pages. After making this change it started working for me.

On the other pages I was using same code so there was no issue with the code I found that issue is with the code on Login page. After login and redirect user on any page everything works perfect in virtual user.

I already opened a ticket in Sitecore for same they are into investigation why it is not working if we are getting any profile properties at the time of login.

We have tested this Virtual user functionality with multiple login at the same time and honestly it is working perfect. So I would say the Virtual feature is the really cool feature provided by Sitecore but on one point we need to be more careful. I hope Sitecore will resolve this issue in next releases or will provide patch for same.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life with this, we had custom properties disappearing across different environments at different times with the same code, and all because of trying to extract a custom property in a menu before possibly being logged in. Did you ever get a fix from Sitecore or other explanation?

Comment: @WulfgarDK I haven't got any fix from Sitecore

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
In my case it was multiple domains. I created a virtual user at domain1.test.local and expected it at domain2.test.local. That doesn't work because the ASP.NET session cookie is domain specific.

Answer (score -5):

Try to clear the cache by using below code before creating user.

```cs
if (Sitecore.Context.ClientData != null)
{
    var ClientDataValues = Sitecore.Context.ClientData.GetValueNames();
    if (ClientDataValues != null && ClientDataValues.Any())
    {
        var KeyName = "SC_USR_" + userName;
        var clientDataValue = Sitecore.Context.ClientData.GetValue(KeyName);
        if (clientDataValue != null)
        {
            Sitecore.Context.ClientData.RemoveValue(KeyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Can you add some details regarding what this code is doing, the possible outcomes you are expecting and what you hope this code will accomplish? If you consider this a production-ready solution wherein you always evict the user from cache on each request, please explain why this will not adversely affect performance or other native logic.

Comment: please provide detailed explanation